# How to restore a backed up directory

Tags: 16.04, restore, aws

When I attempted to upgrade 15.10 to 16.04 the upgrade failed and corrupted my instance. Before doing so I backed up my /home directory to AWS as a tar.gz file. How can I restore this file/directory to my new fresh installation - or at the least, how can I recover the files from within the zip? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have downloaded the `.tar.gz` file from AWS you can either double click on it in `nautilus` and pull the files out by using the `archive-manager` or you could when you know the path to your file simply unpack it in terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) by:

```
cd /path-where-you-want-to-unpack/
tar -xf /pat-to-your-archive/archive-name.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you - nautilus didn't recognize the file as a backup - but running the unpack in terminal seems to be working so far - the file is 6.5 gb and it appears to be unpacking now - just hoping it successfully unzips - thanks for your help.

Comment: This did work successfully - thank you very much for the command. I've made a ton of backups previously and failed to restore them the few times I needed to - this was the first successful restore at a time i needed it to work - thanks again.

Comment: Youre very welcome